# css keyframes rotate words vertically

Tags: html, css

I want to rotate a word with css keyframes. After the second word appeard, there´s a blank and first after some seconds the first word is appearing again. The word should rotate vertical. this works. I only can´t make it work, that after the second word the first word is visible immediatly

my Code:

```css
.rw-words{
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 10px;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #e54517;
 -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
 animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
 animation-delay: 3s; 
 color: #e54517;
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
 5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-30px); }
 5% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 20% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(30px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); transform: translateY(-30px); }
 5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px); }
 20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); transform: translateY(90px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
                            <span>steuern.</span>
                            <span>erkennen.</span>
                        </div>
```

can´t see the mistake

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want? Perhaps I can help you out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
.rw-words-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #e54517;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
    animation-delay: 3s; 
    color: #e54517;
}
```

by this:

```
.rw-words-1 span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #e54517;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 6s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 6s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: rotateWord 6s linear infinite 0s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  color: #e54517;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ub669jg5/)

Your initial code waited for the whole 18 seconds to complete before restarting.

Comment: ahhh. overlooked this line after the time. thanks :)